# Making a space between table headings

Tags: tables

I want to replicate the table in this image but without the second column:

[image]

However the problem is that I'm unable to find out how to make a horizontal space between each two columns (N=2, N=3 ... etc). Also I'm not able to find out how to make a vertical space between the first row and the second row (N=2 and Avg. Pos ... etc) because the text is too close to the upperline.

Here is my version and code:

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lrrrrrr@{}}
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{N = 2}                                     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{N = 3}                                     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{N = 4}                                      \\  \cline{2-3} \cline{4-5} \cline{6-7} 
        Network Name       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Avg. Pos.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Avg. Neg.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Avg. Pos.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Avg. Neg.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Avg. Pos.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Avg. Neg.} \\ \midrule
        X            & 4895                          & 135639                        & 77                            & 109622                        & 5                             & 16360                         \\ 
        Y               & 5426                          & 183685                        & 196                           & 204801                        & 9                             & 39977                         \\ 
        Z & 8959                          & 80669                         & 38                            & 109362                        & 4                             & 43329                         \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For first, use `\cmidrule(lr){2-3}`, note `(lr)`. For details, consult the `booktabs` manual. For second, use some `strut` like

```
\newcommand*{\mystrut}{\rule{0pt}{2.5ex}}
```

Change `2.5ex` as you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand*{\mystrut}{\rule{0pt}{2.5ex}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lrrrrrr@{}}
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{N = 2}                                     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{N = 3}                                     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{N = 4}                                      \\  \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
     \mystrut   Network Name       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Avg. Pos.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Avg. Neg.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Avg. Pos.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Avg. Neg.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Avg. Pos.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Avg. Neg.} \\ \midrule
        X            & 4895                          & 135639                        & 77                            & 109622                        & 5                             & 16360                         \\
        Y               & 5426                          & 183685                        & 196                           & 204801                        & 9                             & 39977                         \\
        Z & 8959                          & 80669                         & 38                            & 109362                        & 4                             & 43329                         \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you check whether this table will fit within the width of the text block?

Answer (score 3):

A solution that uses `booktabs`, `makecell` (that allows for line breaks in cells) and  `siunitx` for  centred-rightaligned numbers, plus `\extrarowheight` for a better vertical spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{table-format=6.0}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccSS[table-format=3.0]ScS[table-format=5.0]@{}}
    \toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{N = 2} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{N = 3} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{N = 4} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
   \makecell{ Network\\ Name} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Avg. Pos.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Avg. Neg.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Avg. Pos.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Avg. Neg.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Avg. Pos.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Avg. Neg.} \\
   \cmidrule[\lightrulewidth](lr){1-1}\cmidrule[\lightrulewidth](lr){2-3}\cmidrule[\lightrulewidth](lr){4-5}\cmidrule[\lightrulewidth](lr){6-7}
    X & 4895 & 135639 & 77 & 109622 & 5 & 16360 \\
    Y & 5426 & 183685 & 196 & 204801 & 9 & 39977 \\
    Z & 8959 & 80669 & 38 & 109362 & 4 & 43329 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses the `tabular*` instead of a `tabular` environment. This assures that the table will fit within the assigned width of `\textblock`. With this approach, doing explicit trimming of the lines created by `\cmidrule` turns out to be unnecessary. The use of `\cmidrule` instead of `\cline` will automatically provide the extra vertical separation you say you wish to get.

To make this table fit in the text block, it is necessary to introduce line breaks in the "Avg. Pos." and "Avg. Neg." strings. I would further suggest that you use a column type that automatically aligns the numbers on their (implied) decimal points; one such column type is the `d` type of the `dcolumn` package. (The `S` column type of the `siunitx` package would work as well.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}    % two handy shortcut macros
\newcommand\MC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{#1}}

\usepackage{dcolumn}  % decimal marker alignment functions
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{} l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
             d{4.0}d{6.0} d{3.0}d{6.0} d{1.0}d{5.0} @{}}
        \toprule
        Network Name 
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$N = 2$} 
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$N = 3$}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{$N = 4$}\\  
        \cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{6-7}
        & \mc{Avg.} & \mc{Avg.} & \mc{Avg.} & \mc{Avg.} & \mc{Avg.} & \MC{Avg.} \\
        & \mc{Pos.} & \mc{Neg.} & \mc{Pos.} & \mc{Neg.} & \mc{Pos.} & \MC{Neg.} \\
        \midrule
        X & 4895 & 135639 &  77 & 109622 & 5 & 16360 \\
        Y & 5426 & 183685 & 196 & 204801 & 9 & 39977 \\
        Z & 8959 &  80669 &  38 & 109362 & 4 & 43329 \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```